# Random string function sometimes returns null

Tags: php, function, random

I am using this to generate a random number 0-3 and it works fine except every now and then it will return null and I'm not sure why. Any ideas would be great

```
function genRandomString($length=1,$characters = '0123',$string = '') {
for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
}

return $string; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StrLen($characters) returns 4
mt_rand(0,4) will result in Random numbers ranging from 0 to inclusive 4.

$characters has a length of 4, sou you can access it from $characters[0] to $characters[3].
If you generate a random 4, you access $characters[4], and so you get your null

Comment: ah, is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: yes
$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];

Comment: your welcome.
also try stereofrogs approach to set error_reportong to E_ALL so you will get error messages

Answer (score -2):

Why would you need a user created function for something already possible with a native PHP function?

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) echo mt_rand(0, 3) . "\n";
```

[codepad here](http://codepad.org/G46XP3J1)

Comment: I use the function also when not dealing with a strictly numeric sting which I think your example has to be numeric.

Comment: 2? [Here's an example with 5](http://codepad.org/YJmzU0N6). If you want a single sample you could [do away with the outer loop](http://codepad.org/eGGcyPtS).

Comment: yeah but now we're getting just as complicated as using a function :)

Comment: I agree. My comment was a response to what you stated as the reason for using the function: *I am using this to generate a random number 0-3*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3394/discussion-between-bandonrandon-and-majid-fouladpour)